# creating tile icon in WP7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to create an tile icon inside my WP7 application. It should look like the same tile icon in WP7 home screen. How do I create those tile icons inside my WP7 app using C# code or XAML code.

Comment: You shouldn't create an application which looks liek the start screen as this can be confusing to users. (Would you create a PC app which looks like the desktop?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.

If you just want to show an image/icon then you can use an Image control - you can load this from an image embedded as Content or as an EmbeddedResource.

If you want to show more animated "live tiles" then try the HubTile in http://silverlight.codeplex.com/ - http://igrali.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/how-to-use-the-hubtile-control/

[image: image from igrali.wordpress.com]

Comment: Please note that the `HubTile` is intended to be used to recreate the functionality seen in the hubs, not the home screen.